# Ajax response from server. Add to a div

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am doing the following:
I have a modal, with a POST to the server.
Before returning to the view (where the bootstrap modal is configured to relaunch)
I stored some info in ViewData: something like this:

```
ViewData["Msg"] = "<div id=\"msgResponse\" class=\"success alert-success alert-dismissable\">" +
                "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">×</button>" +
                "<strong>Success!!</strong> .....</div>";
```

I want to load the content of it and append to another div, how can I do this?

Comment: ViewData is pointless in this instance. You could just return a PartialView as your result where the view has all your HTML. It does appear (as @Kamo suggests) that you only need to return a status and do the rest client-side. Please show your controller code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have some controller action method in C# server side code as follows:

C# code:

```
public ActionResult gethtml_mymethod()
{
    ViewData["Msg"] = "<div id=\"msgResponse\" class=\"success alert-success alert-dismissable\">" +
                "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">×</button>" +
                "<strong>Success!!</strong> .....</div>";

    return View("html_myview", mymodel);        
}
```

You should have `html_myview.ascx` something like follows:

```
<div id="Msg_Container">
    <%=ViewData["Msg"]%>
</div>
......
......
<div>
     Some HTML view
</div>
```

Now in modal popup Ajax call you can fetch it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/mycontroller/gethtml_mymethod",
   data: someJsonData,
   success: function(response){
       response = $("<div>"+response+"</div>");
       var MsgHTML = response.find("#Msg_Container").html(); //id = Msg_Container is present in html_myview.ascx
       var myAnotherDiv = $("#myAnotherDiv");//this div is where you want to append message
       myAnotherDiv.append(MsgHTML );
   }
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of pointless returning a view containing hard-wired HTML from a string? The whole problem should be far simpler and *not* server-side based (aside from a simple status return of course).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you returning whole div in you response?

If you have an AJAX call, you can return serialized response with JSON using  JsonResult like following:

`return new JsonResult(new Json({Message = "Success"}));`

which will be read by JQuery Ajax function. Then it can be appended to your div.

If you edit your question and add controller and JS code which you are using, I can edit my answer then with more details.